# Application crashing when another activity is added

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an android application that logs in the user via **email authentication** through **firebase** and on successful login the app will shift to another activity.
Now the problem is while the single activity for login is working fine but as soon as I add another activity on which it has to jump and try to run again then this error

> NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;

comes up and the application automatically closes. 
I have tried many different options but none of them works. Have restarted my pc, invalidated the cache but still no luck.

.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.arviadmin"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arviadmin">
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Share your build.gradle file

Comment: Added the .gradle file. @ZUNJAE

Comment: please error stack trace

Comment: After some googling it seems like this is related to the version for your com.android.support. Have you considered migrating to AndroidX?

Comment: A lot of threads with similar error suggest that you should invalidate caches and restart (from the File menu)

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I did that but still didn't work out.

Comment: Could you add the Manifest.xml?

Comment: @GabrielFerreira added the Manifest.xml file.

Comment: can you share `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity` code?

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file seems fine. If everything in LoginActivity, MainActivity and xml are correct I suggest you to delete the build folders - because you have already `invalidate the cache`.

```
project-folder/build
project-folder/app/build
```

If it still don't work I suggest you to comment everything on those classes and start uncommenting while testing.